# How can l rename a set of directories given the list of new names?

Tags: command-line, python, directory, rename

l would like to rename my directories following a list of new names.

l am wondering hoc can l take advantage of using the following command to rename a set of directories which are in the same principal directory.

```
find . -type d -name 'thefoldername*' -exec mv {} newfoldername \;
```

The actual directory names are :

```
Actual_folder_names=['archery','benchpressing','bikingthroughsnow','blowingoutcandles','bowling','brushingteeth','cleanandjerk','divingcliff','drummingfingers','golfchipping','golfdriving']
```

change to :

```
new_folder_name=['Archery' ,'BenchPress' ,'Biking' ,'BlowingCandles' ,'Bowling' ,'BrushingTeeth','CleanAndJerk' ,'Diving' ,'Drumming'
,'GolfSwing1', 'GolfSwing2']
```

Thank you

Comment: How should the computer know where to capitalize? You want to move `brushingteeth` to `BrushingTeeth`, but how should it know where to put upper case letters?

Comment: for that case l can do it manually l just have few of them. Just ignore this case

Comment: Where do these names come from? what language are you trying to do this in (your list syntax looks pythonesque)?

Comment: yes they are in python format. They represent names of data

Comment: So why not do it inside python (using `zip` to iterate over the lists pairwise + `os.rename`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put the two lists of names in text files to do the renaming like this :

Create the two lists

```
echo "'archery','benchpressing','bikingthroughsnow','blowingoutcandles','bowling','brushingteeth','cleanandjerk','divingcliff','drummingfingers','golfchipping','golfdriving'" |sed -e "s/'//g ; s/,/\n/g" > listorig
echo "'Archery' ,'BenchPress' ,'Biking' ,'BlowingCandles' ,'Bowling' ,'BrushingTeeth','CleanAndJerk' ,'Diving' ,'Drumming','GolfSwing1', 'GolfSwing2'" |sed -e "s/'//g ; s/,/\n/g" > listdest
```

Put the two lists side by side and do the job  in "Dry run" mode

```
paste listorig listdest | awk '{print "mv " $0}'
```

If the check is good, really do the job :

```
paste listorig listdest | awk '{print "mv " $0}' |sh
```

And the job is done :)